# i have to make a relation between movie and actor without using manytomany field i have to use only foreign key in django i've write this code so far

Tags: python, django, django-3.0, python-django-storages

```
models.py


    class Movielist(models.Model) :
        Title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
        Description = models.TextField(blank=True)
        ReleaseDate = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Release Date', blank=True)
        # NoOfActors = models.IntegerField()
        Upvote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        Downvote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        
        def __str__(self):
            return self.Title

    class Actorlist(models.Model):
        Name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
        DateofBirth = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Date of Birth',blank=True)
        # NoOfActors = models.IntegerField()
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.Name

    class ActorInMovie(models.Model):
        Movie = models.ForeignKey(Movielist, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
        Actor = models.ForeignKey(Actorlist, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
        
        def __str__(self):
            return self.Movie.Title



views.py


    def Movie_Detail(request):
        MovieName = Movielist.objects.all()
        tablelist = ActorInMovie.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'Collection/index.html', {'MovieName':MovieName, 'tablelist':tablelist})



index.html
<table border="solid">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Release Date</th>
        <th>Actors</th>
        {% for data in MovieName %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ data.Title }}</td>
            <td>{{ data.ReleaseDate }}</td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    {% for name in tablelist %}
                    <li>{{ name.Actor.Name }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

**i have getting this out put can any any one tell me how to filter this data only my movie id i would like if someone come and help me in solving this problem
[this is the output what i am getting but i want filter actors name by movielist.id][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlAuP.png**
```

Comment: Why do you _have_ to not use a ManyToManyField? Your ActorInMovie model is basically a through table for a many-to-many relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting all the objects in ActorInMovie into `tablelist`, and not just the related ones. You don't need the `tablelist` at all. Instead:

```html
        {% for data in MovieName %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ data.Title }}</td>
            <td>{{ data.ReleaseDate }}</td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    {% for movie_actor in data.ActorInMovie %}
                    <li>{{ movie_actor.Actor.Name }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

You might also need to use `related_name` in your `ActorInMovie` model to tell django how you'll identify the related fields:

`Movie = models.ForeignKey(Movielist, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, related_name='ActorInMovie`)

Since you're going to print all the actors of every movie, it's a good idea to use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)([Another ref](https://medium.com/codeptivesolutions/prefetch-related-and-select-related-in-django-90f07a2379c0)) to achieve better performance, but it's not required if you don't have a lot of data.

Comment: hi can you tell me how can i do this with a django rest framwork